# Retrieving Nth subquery for INSERT

Tags: mysql, subquery

#### Abstract

From a table holding various posts of users to a forum, another table shall be daily updated with the top 20 posters. Posts are stored in `posts`, daily high-scores are held in `hiscore`.

#### Tables

```
posts:
   post_id(PK:INT) | user_id(INT) | ... | timestamp(TIMESTAMP)

hiscore:
   user_id(INT) | rank(INT)
```

#### Query

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `hiscore` ;
INSERT INTO `hiscore` (`user_id`,`rank`)
 (
   SELECT `user_id`, ???
   FROM `posts`
   WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN blah AND blah
   GROUP BY `user_id`
   ORDER BY COUNT(`post_id`) DESC
   LIMIT 20
 )
```

#### The actual question

What is to be inserted in the above query instead of `???` to account for the rank?

Is there a variable like `@NTH_SUBQUERY` that'll substitute for 5 on the fifth run of the `SELECT` subquery?

---

**UPDATE:** The table `hiscore` is supposed to *only* hold the top 20 posters. I know the table structure can be optimized. The focus of the answers should be on how to determine the current retrieved row of the sub-query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems too fancy on `truncate`, for you cases

```
hiscore:
   the_date (DATE) | user_id(INT) | rank(INT)
```

and built a key on `the_date, rank`

**insertion**

```
set @pos=0;

insert into hiscore
select cur_date(), user_id, @pos:=@pos+1
from ...
```

to keep the table size manageable, you probably can delete once in few months

Or you can set an auto_increment on `rank`

```
create table hiscore
(
  the_date date not null,
  rank int(3) not null auto_increment,
  user_id int(10) not null,
  primary key (the_date, rank)
);
```

So, the rank is auto incremented (which is the same as order by number of daily posts descending)

Comment: Thanks so much for your input. I tried to avoid mentioning the `auto_increment` in the question (since it's valid, no doubt). But *is there a way to determine the number/index of the current sub-query?*

Comment: `set @pos:=0; select cur_date(), user_id, @pos:=@pos+1 from ...`

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO `hiscore` (`user_id`,`rank`)
 (
   SELECT `user_id`, @rank = @rank + 1
   FROM `posts`, (SELECT @rank := 0) r
   WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN blah AND blah
   GROUP BY `user_id`
   ORDER BY COUNT(`post_id`) DESC
   LIMIT 20
 )
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks like it's *supposed* to work. Yet when running this query in phpMyAdmin, all rows have zeros as rank.